# Cannot lock xml write using lock() or Mutex

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, locking, mutex

I am writing a simple application which writes to a single xml file for around 1000 iterations from multiple threads .
I have tried using the lock() ,Mutex and the ReaderWriterSlim to lock the file while its being written. It works for some time but gives error about the file is being accessed by another process. 
Can somebody please help me to get some solution :

Or is there any other way to achieve this .

```
public class XmlWrite
{
    //private static object _lock = new Object();


    static string xmlFilePath = "C:\\Test\\Multi.xml";
    public static Mutex m_Mutex = new Mutex(false, @"Global\MyMutex");

    public static void LogXML(object threadID)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 1000)
        {
            try
            {
                m_Mutex.WaitOne();
                XmlDocument xml = LoadDocument(xmlFilePath);

                var xmlElement = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(xml));

                var sourceXElement = new XElement("ParentNode");
                sourceXElement.Add(new XElement("ChildNode", threadID));

                xmlElement.Add(sourceXElement);

                SaveDocument(xmlElement, xmlFilePath);

                Console.WriteLine("Value " + xml.ToString() + "Index" + i + "Thread" + threadID.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exe.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                m_Mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }

    public static XmlDocument LoadDocument(String path)
    {
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7")))
        {
            document.Load(stream);

        }
        return (document);
    }

    public static XElement SaveDocument(XElement document, String path)
    {
        using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(path, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7")))
        {
            document.Save(stream);
        }
        return (document);
    }


}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        new Thread(XmlWrite.LogXML).Start("A");
        new Thread(XmlWrite.LogXML).Start("B");
        new Thread(XmlWrite.LogXML).Start("C");
        new Thread(XmlWrite.LogXML).Start("D");
        new Thread(XmlWrite.LogXML).Start("E");
        new Thread(XmlWrite.LogXML).Start("F");
        new Thread(XmlWrite.LogXML).Start("G");
        new Thread(XmlWrite.LogXML).Start("H");
        new Thread(XmlWrite.LogXML).Start("i");
    }
}
```

Comment: The file seems to be properly guarded by the mutex. Are you sure there aren't any other process (other than the code above) that access the file without acquiring the mutex? It might be that there is an editor or something that is accessing the file.

Comment: I changed the approach and even now the code is throwing the exception . I had to read and write from same file. There is another application/process to read the same . Hence the reason I used the named mutex. Not sure even with mutex multi threaded write gives the same exception.